# Can't understand why the code shows incorrect output. The output should be 1 and yes but instead of yes it shows No

Tags: python-3.x

Iam learning python and wanted to test the concept of list and if/else function.

```
num1 = ["1"]
c = num1[0]
print(c)
if num1[0] == 1:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

I expect the output to be 1 yes
but I get the output as 1 no
why does it not enter if block even when the condition is met

Answer (score 3):

Arent you comparing string with integer? try `if (num[0]=="1")`